# Export to HTML from Win7 PowerShell v2

Tags: html, powershell-2.0

Export to HTML from Win7 PowerShell v2
I am trying to run several checks on different settings and print them out in an easy to read format. I'm using Win7 PowerShell V2
I pulled all this from a website and it works when I have tables:

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:palegoldenrod}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$Variable
$VariableHTML = ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>Title I want</H2>"

$VariableHTML > C:\PoSH\My_Exported_HTML.html
```

My main issue is my $variable is no longer a table. It is one word Pass/Fail. I would like to have a title on one line, definition on the second line, and the result smaller and on the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML

```
$VariableHTML = $Variable | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H1>Header One</H1> <H2>Header Two</H2> <H3>Header Three</H3> <p>Paragraph<p/>"
```

I wanted to be able to add additional headers (though I didn't know what they were called) and a small caption line (paragraph).